# Creating a Java Application to decrypt Sqlcipher database

Tags: java, android, encryption, intellij-idea, sqlcipher

I am new to Java programming and was recently tasked with creating a Java Program that will allow us to decrypt a copy of a database so that we can check it for errors. I did some research and found the SQLite code that would be needed for the decryption and how to include it in my program but I am unsure of how to grab the database and create a decrypted copy of the database.

I am using a Mac and the Intellij IDE.

I have included the code I have come up with so far and the code I know I will need to perform the decryption but I am unsure of what else I need. Any advice / guidance is greatly appreciated.

```
import android.content.*;
import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase; 
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class decrypt{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dbPath;
        String passphrase;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter database path");
        dbPath = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter passphrase");
        passphrase = in.nextLine();

        // so now i have the db path and the passphrase to go with it
        // below is the code I found that will be needed to decrypt a sqlcipher encrypted database


        db.rawExecSQL(String.format("ATTACH DATABASE '%s' AS plaintext KEY '%s';",
                                    newFile.getAbsolutePath(), passphrase));
        db.rawExecSQL("SELECT sqlcipher_export('plaintext')");
        db.rawExecSQL("DETACH DATABASE plaintext;");
}
```

Comment: You have this tagged `android`. Is that really where you are planning on doing this decryption? Android apps normally do not implement a `public static void main()` method, which is why I ask. Also, the SQLCipher for Android classes that you appear to be trying to use are for Android, not desktop Java.

Comment: The company I work for has android applications and we need to be able to access the databases created within those applications so we can analyze them and look for errors.

Comment: That did not answer my question. You typed in some code into your question. Are you planning on running this code on an Android device, or not?

Comment: I apologize, I read the question wrong. No we are not. We would run the code on our MacBooks

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the `net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabse` class, in addition to being misspelled, is only available as part of SQLCipher for Android and therefore will only run on Android.

For what you are looking to do, a shell script that runs the command-line edition of SQLCipher may suffice. Regardless, you need to use [something that will run on your desired platform](http://sqlcipher.net/documentation), though there may not be a Java API for it.

Comment: I will look into how to create the shell script and how to set up a command-line edition of SQLCipher. Thank you for your assistance

Comment: The SQLCipher home page says Java is a supported platform (aside from Android).  Is this not true?

Comment: @Michael: I do not see it listed in [the documentation](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/documentation/). Even if it were supported, it would not be via Android-specific classes. SQLCipher for Android only replaces the necessary Android classes, not reusable common ones like `Cursor`. Yet, Java does not have Android's `Cursor` class.